# Event Grid Topic Vs Event Grid System Topic

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-logic-apps, azure-eventgrid, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

1. What's the difference between **Event Grid Topic** and **Event Grid System Topic**.

When I select resource type "**Event Grid Custom Topic**" then **Event Grid Topic type** is getting created.

but when I use Service Bus Premium->Event Registration .  The Event Grid System Topic type is getting created.

Question is which one is more efficient and which one to use.  As I am using **endpoint type webhook** and calling my logic app event whenever the message is posted to my service bus queue/topics.

Whereas in **EventGrid Custom Topic** I have to use the **Event Grid Trigger** in my logic app and the event custom topic automatically gets created.

Please tell me the difference between these two and when to use which and which is more efficient

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

System Topics are used by Azure Services like Azure Storage, etc. Previously they were implicit but have recently been [exposed as Azure Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/system-topics#system-topics-as-azure-resources).

From a performance aspect, there should be no difference between the topic types. Both types support the same type of [event handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-handlers) as well.

One major difference is that there is no endpoint or access keys for system topics to publish events like for custom topics.

Comment: I'm trying to setup DeadLettering for a System Topic. Following the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/manage-event-delivery#azure-cli). Results are `ERROR: The Resource 'Microsoft.EventGrid/topics/system-topic-test-dev' under resource group 'TEST_DEV' was not found.`. Is DeadLettering possible with System Topics?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Event Grid Topic provides more features in Settings and Monitoring.

[Only Azure services can publish events to system topics. Therefore, you don't get an endpoint or access keys that you can use to publish events like you do for custom topics or event domains.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/system-topics)

[Event Grid Topic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Gpsp.png)
[Event Grid System Topic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTES6.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.